# Date Picker in a Custom Dialog (not a DatePickerDialog) Restrict Past Dates Not Working

Tags: android, datepicker, customdialog

I created a Date Picker in a Custom Dialog not in DatepickerDialog as usually people do.
Problem is When I try to restrict the past dates, on runtime app crashes, log cat out put i attached. There might be something I missed in my code [attached], please help.

```
04-30 10:24:16.278: D/dalvikvm(19320): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1764K, 27% free 9106K/12412K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 32ms
04-30 10:24:16.278: D/dalvikvm(19320): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320): java.lang.StackOverflowError
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getChars(SpannableStringBuilder.java:913)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:75)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:75)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.text.TextUtils.indexOf(TextUtils.java:108)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:182)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:288)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:174)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:5952)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5850)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6391)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3672)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3530)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3505)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.updateInputTextView(NumberPicker.java:1763)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.NumberPicker.setDisplayedValues(NumberPicker.java:1381)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateSpinners(DatePicker.java:642)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:545)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:699)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:547)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:699)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:547)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:699)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:547)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:699)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:547)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:699)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:547)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:699)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:547)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:699)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:547)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:699)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:547)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:699)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:547)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:699)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:547)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:699)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:547)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(DatePicker.java:699)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDate(DatePicker.java:547)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at com.view.MyProject.SchedulesActivity$28.onDateChanged(SchedulesActivity.java:1328)
04-30 10:24:16.282: E/AndroidRuntime(19320):    at android.widget.DatePicker.notifyDateChanged(
```

code:

```
DatePicker  datePicker  =   (DatePicker)datePickerDialog.findViewById(R.id.datepicker);
        getCurrDate();

        datePicker.init(year, month, day, new OnDateChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int selected_year, int selected_month,
                    int selected_day) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /// getCurrDate();
                if (selected_year < currYear)
                    view.updateDate(currYear, currMonth, currDay);


                if (selected_month < currMonth && selected_year == currYear);
                    view.updateDate(currYear, currMonth, currDay);

                if (selected_month < currDay && year == currYear && selected_month == currMonth)
                    view.updateDate(currYear, currMonth, currDay);

                selectedDate = ""+(selected_month+1)+"/"+selected_day+"/"+selected_year;
                datePicker_TV.setText(selectedDate);

                repeatDlgDoneBtn.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Dialog_cancel_blue));
                repeatDlgDoneBtn.setEnabled(true);
                getSelectedWeek();
            }
        });     
        datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);         
        datePicker.setDescendantFocusability(DatePicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
        datePickerDialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry For Bad Programming, view.UpdateDate() cannot be called in init( anonymous inner class type..)
That's Why the crash is there, though same logic is applicable when DatePickerDialog Object is taken like this:

```
  new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated
.................................
.................................
same logic as above code works  for this scenario. 

But i had used a Custom Dialog to  increase UI Flexibility, so here's the perfect solution:
1. 1st get the Time in Millis for the Past Date[Called Min Date to be set in Date Picker]
2. If it is Current Date then do not use current time System.getCurrentTimeinMillis(); as it's always greater than the Actual date's Initial Time so using this will crash DatePicker. Instead send this current date to a date to time converter function as i had mentioned below:





public void getCurrDate()
    {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return ""+(month+1)+"/"+day+"/"+year;
    }
    String input = getCurrDate();
            Date date;
            try {
                date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(input);
                long milliseconds = date.getTime();
                if(milliseconds>0){
                    datePicker.setMinDate(milliseconds);
  //This Function will work fine, to set a future constraint use setMaxDate(long time); 
                }
                else
                {
                               //whatever else cond...
                }

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```